# C# incorrect syntax near the keyword "inner"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I work on a project and the problem I have is that I want to show the history of a customer's order.
the error i get is this "Incorrect syntax near the keyword "inner"
I use C# windows Form and MSSQL

```
d2 = new SqlDataAdapter("Select 
LastName,AFM,TYPE,CATEGORY,SalePrice,FPA,Quantity,Final_Price" +
"FROM CUSTOMER inner join(ORDER inner join PRODUCT_ORDER" +
"on ORDER.ID_ORDER = PRODUCT_ORDER.ID_ORDER inner join STORE on 
PRODUCT_ORDER.K_E = STORE.KE)" +
"on CUSTOMER.CUST_ID = ORDER.CUST_ID WHERE LASTNAME='" + 
comboBox1.Text.ToString()+ "'", connect);
ds2 = new DataSet();
b2 = new BindingSource();
d2.Fill(ds2);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds2.Tables[0].DefaultView;
double sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
  double quantity = 
Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
  double fpa = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
  double SalePrice = 
Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
  sum = SalePrice * quantity * (fpa / 100);
}

label4.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
```

Comment: You get this error from SQL after running the query, or in the designer? Your first line doesn't continue correctly (after the `Select`) to the next line, and you don't leave spaces from one line to the next which results in an incorrect string.

Comment: This is because you don't have spaces between your words in your string. You could also simplify this with some aggregation instead of calculating it after you get the rows. But before you write another line of code you need to read about, understand and start using parameters in your queries. My friend [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) loves code like this.

Comment: "Order" looks like it should be in brackets as a keyword.

Comment: What is *"`inner join(ORDER inner join`"* supposed to mean? `ORDER` is a reserved keyword in SQL Server, so if it is an object, it needs to be quoted. Then you have the `(` before it, which appears to be totally random and you're missing your `ON` clause. Also, this is open to injection, you need to parametrise your queries.

Comment: There are so many syntactical and logical errors here in addition to the injection problems.

Comment: @SeanLange We haven't even mentioned the declared variables not being used.  Or the `.Text.ToString()` redundancy. Or that SelectedItem or SelectedValue is probably the property the user wants to use on that ComboBox instead of Text.

Comment: @LarsTech good points. My head was already spinning too much to notice much else.

Comment: @Larnu *`inner join ([ORDER] inner join`* is *part* of a rarely used syntax. It's primarily used to do an outer join of two or more inner-joined tables, e.g. `FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN (b INNER JOIN c ON c.x = b.x) ON b.Id = a.Id` so that the inner join doesn't exclude rows that were kept by the outer join. It's more common to use a derived table. In this case, the syntax is correct (if you assume whitespace at the string concatenations) but it's unnecesary because it's all inner joins.

Comment: Probably a good idea to learn some SQL syntax before writing a query.

Comment: For that syntax, the parenthesis are actually superfluous @madreflection. and as they are all an `INNER JOIN` doubly so. The only time you really see syntax where you "delay" the `ON` clause is with a `LEFT JOIN`. Like `FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 INNER JOIN T3 ON T3.fid = T2.ID ON T2.fID = T1.ID`. Both joins being an `INNER JOIN` means that you might as well just use "normal" syntax and save the confusion.

Comment: @Larnu My point exactly.

Answer (score 0):

That query looks like it was generated by the MS Access query designer.  The style is very dated.

This is probably more like what it should be:

```
string sql = "SELECT LastName, AFM, TYPE, CATEGORY, SalePrice, FPA, Quantity, Final_Price " + 
    "FROM CUSTOMER c " + 
    "INNER JOIN [ORDER] o ON  c.CUST_ID = o.CUST_ID " + 
    "INNER JOIN PRODUCT_ORDER p ON o.ID_ORDER = p.ID_ORDER " + 
    "INNER JOIN STORE s ON  p.K_E = s.KE " + 
    "WHERE c.LASTNAME =@LastName";
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("", connect);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", ComboBox1.Text.Tostring());
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter d2 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

The query still needs work.  I'd add table qualifiers on the fields in the select command.  Don't forget to dispose of objects once you are done with them (or use using)

Comment: The Access Query designer (unless it was fixed in the last few decades) would have added a ton more ((unnecessary) (parentheses)).